# Folder vs File Folder - Can I create a folder from the command line?

Tags: windows-explorer

If I create a shortcut to a folder and drag the shortcut onto the start menu, then the shortcut on the start menu behaves just like any other shortcut - click it to open the folder in explorer.

However, if I drag the *folder* onto the start menu, then it expands in-situ. If I then copy this shortcut(?) into another location on my machine and compare it to other files/folders, its type appears as "Folder" as opposed to "File Folder" (which is what I get when I choose File->New->Folder.

What's the difference between these two types of folder?

Can I create one of these folders without dragging onto the start menu?

Thanks

---

With the help of zildjohn01 I've found out that these are called "Junction Points".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question... I never knew this behavior existed. I managed to recreate it without drag-n-drop.

1. Create the new folder (for example `C:\xyz`)
2. Put the following in `desktop.ini` in the new folder

   > [.ShellClassInfo]
   >   CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
   >   Flags=2
3. Create a shortcut named `target.lnk` in the folder pointing to the desired destination folder.
4. Add the system attribute to the folder

   > C:\>attrib +s xyz